# how to zip (single zip file) multiple pandas dataframes after converting it to xlsx?

Tags: python, pandas

currently I am converting the dataframes to csv and then zipping using the following code:

```
dfDict = {'df_1_name.csv': df1, 'df_2_name.csv': df2}

def makeZip(self, path, dfDict):
  fileNames = dfDict.keys()
  if len(fileNames) > 0:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'w') as csv_zip:
      for file in fileNames:
        csv_zip.writestr(file, dfDict[file].to_csv(index=False),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
  return
```

I found that `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` function exists, but can't figure out how to use it in a similar way as above

Answer (score 0):

You can use different sheets for your DataFrames, you can use something similar to:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

then, if you also want to zip it, just zip `output.xlsx` .

Comment: I want to create different files for each dataframe

Comment: then you can just create different `ExcelWriters` initialised with different filenames